# Elastisearch.net property opt in?

Tags: nest, elasticsearch-net

I'm using Elastisearch.NET with NEST 2.3. I want to use attribute mapping but I only want to index certain properties. As I understand it all properties are indexed unless you ignore them using for example [String(Ignore = true)] Is it possible to ignore all properties by default and only index the ones that have a nest attribute attached to them? Like JSON.NETs MemberSerialization.OptIn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using a custom serializer to ignore any properties not marked with a NEST `ElasticsearchPropertyAttributeBase` derived attribute.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(
        pool, 
        new HttpConnection(), 
        new SerializerFactory(s => new CustomSerializer(s)));

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    client.CreateIndex("demo", c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<Document>(mm => mm
                .AutoMap()
            )
        )
    );
}

public class Document
{
    [String]
    public string Field1 { get; set;}

    public string Field2 { get; set; }

    [Number(NumberType.Integer)]
    public int Field3 { get; set; }

    public int Field4 { get; set; }
}

public class CustomSerializer : JsonNetSerializer
{
    public CustomSerializer(IConnectionSettingsValues settings, Action<JsonSerializerSettings, IConnectionSettingsValues> settingsModifier) : base(settings, settingsModifier) { }

    public CustomSerializer(IConnectionSettingsValues settings) : base(settings) { }

    public override IPropertyMapping CreatePropertyMapping(MemberInfo memberInfo)
    {
        // if cached before, return it
        IPropertyMapping mapping;
        if (Properties.TryGetValue(memberInfo.GetHashCode(), out mapping)) 
            return mapping;

        // let the base method handle any types from NEST
        // or Elasticsearch.Net
        if (memberInfo.DeclaringType.FullName.StartsWith("Nest.") ||
            memberInfo.DeclaringType.FullName.StartsWith("Elasticsearch.Net."))
            return base.CreatePropertyMapping(memberInfo);

        // Determine if the member has an attribute
        var attributes = memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true);
        if (attributes == null || !attributes.Any(a => typeof(ElasticsearchPropertyAttributeBase).IsAssignableFrom(a.GetType())))
        {
            // set an ignore mapping
            mapping = new PropertyMapping { Ignore = true };
            Properties.TryAdd(memberInfo.GetHashCode(), mapping);
            return mapping;
        }

        // Let base method handle remaining
        return base.CreatePropertyMapping(memberInfo);
    }
}
```

which produces the following request

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/demo?pretty=true 
{
  "mappings": {
    "document": {
      "properties": {
        "field1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "field3": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```